# List index out of range, but the item exists

Tags: python, list

I get this error and I don't understand why. List index out of range, but the item exists.

```
1 [u'http://(ip1):(port1)', u'http://(ip2):(port2)']
Exception in thread Thread-11:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "(path).py", line 57, in match_fetcher
    self.fetch_match(match)
  File "(path).py", line 65, in fetch_match
    response = self.http_get(url)
  File "(path).py", line 75, in http_get
    proxy = self.proxies.get_proxy()
  File "(path).py", line 51, in get_proxy
    proxy = self.proxies[self.index]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code:

```
def get_proxy(self):

    if self.index >= len(self.proxies):
        self.index = 0
    print self.index, self.proxies
    proxy = self.proxies[self.index]
    self.index += 1
    return proxy
```

I'm confused. What's the problem here?

EDIT:

> You are using threads, is some other one manipulating the same data? –
>   Thierry Lathuille

Output of `cat log | grep (proxy1)`

```
0 [u'(proxy1):(port1)', u'(proxy2):(port2)']
1 [u'(proxy1):(port1)', u'(proxy2):(port2)']
0 [u'(proxy1):(port1)', u'(proxy2):(port2)']
1 [u'(proxy1):(port1)', u'(proxy2):(port2)']
0 [u'(proxy1):(port1)', u'(proxy2):(port2)']
1 [u'(proxy1):(port1)', u'(proxy2):(port2)']
0 [u'(proxy1):(port1)', u'(proxy2):(port2)']
1 [u'(proxy1):(port1)', u'(proxy2):(port2)']
0 [u'(proxy1):(port1)', u'(proxy2):(port2)']
1 [u'(proxy1):(port1)', u'(proxy2):(port2)']
0 [u'(proxy1):(port1)', u'(proxy2):(port2)']
1 [u'(proxy1):(port1)', u'(proxy2):(port2)']
0 [u'(proxy1):(port1)', u'(proxy2):(port2)']
1 [u'(proxy1):(port1)', u'(proxy2):(port2)']
0 [u'(proxy1):(port1)', u'(proxy2):(port2)']
1 [u'(proxy1):(port1)', u'(proxy2):(port2)']
0 [u'(proxy1):(port1)', u'(proxy2):(port2)']
(...)
```

Comment: Could you also print `len(self.proxies)`?

Comment: @georgexsh It returns 2

Comment: You are using threads, is some other one manipulating the same data?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Yes, there are 20 threads, but the value of the index doesn't surpass 1, I have updated question with logs

Comment: I would prefer you do it, other wayy around.

Comment: How can you be sure another thread doesn't increase `self.index` in between your `print` and the indexing?

Comment: Your log shows what happens when all goes well, but what if one thread increments `self.index` when its value is already 1 just before another one tries to access `self.proxies[self.index]`?

Comment: If you let multiple threads call this function without protection, you have what is known as a [*race condition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). The behavior of such events is generally undefined and unpredictable (and usually leads to bad things happening).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a classic thread synchronization problem, twenty threads accessing a shared resource (self.proxies and self.index). Those threads increasing self.index by one, after the if self.index > ... check, which causes it to surpass the size of the list (index > 2).

You need to have some synchronization mechanism to 'protect' your shared resource. A very simple one is a lock:

```
from threading import Lock

# at your init method
self.lock = threading.Lock()

def get_proxy(self):
    self.lock.acquire() # will block if lock is already held
     ... access shared resource
    # basically the entire method in your case
    self.lock.release()
```

I suggest your read more about threads and synchronization, here's a nice tutorial:
https://hackernoon.com/synchronization-primitives-in-python-564f89fee732